# Icon in JLabel is hidden

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, embedded-resource

I tried to load a picture in my `JDialog`.
So, I tried with `JLabel` like  that:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/sau/se/editor/images/HighBtomStPic.png");
System.out.println("Icon exists: "+(icon != null));
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel();
lblNewLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

The `print` gives me **`true`** and I don't see the picture I have inserted, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the file `/sau/se/editor/images/HighBtomStPic.png` actually exist on your computer.

Comment: Consider using ImageIO.read over ImageIcon to load the image

Comment: I changed with that and it has worked, `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(GraphEditor.class    .getResource("/sau/se/editor/images/HighBtomStPic.png"));`

Comment: Please write up an answer to your question so you can accept it. Either that or delete the question, though I bet eitanfar would not like to see that happen.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am dealing with source context not a file system one,

The answer should be:
To replace:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/sau/se/editor/images/HighBtomStPic.png");
```

With:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(GraphEditor.class.getResource("/sau/se/editor/images/HighBtomStPic‌​.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor always returns an instance if it doesn't throw an exception. This is why the `null` check seems ok.

Instead, you should check to see that:
`icon.getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE`

Comment: This means that it wasn't loaded. I doubt that it returned MediaTracker.ABORTED, probably though it was MediaTracker.ERRORED (you can check this easily). If that's the case, it had a problem loading the file. Most usually, the problem is that the path is incorrect, otherwise, it might be that the file is corrupt, or not an image file to begin with.

Comment: JLabel is an ImageObserver, which should allow it to respond to changes in the icons loading state. Might be a good idea to use a MediaTracker to test it, as a suggestion

Comment: Check the load status at any given moment in time could isn't  really a values check, unless trying to loop on it. Just saying